Capacitor Charge and Discharge Circuit
I am trying to make a circuit that charges a cap during the high part of a square wave and discharges it on the low

My theory:
During the high pulse the pmos is off and the nmos is on charging the cap.
During the low the pmos is on and the nmos is off allowing the cap to discharge through the right loop (being disconnected from the left loop).
In LTSPICE:
During the high pulse the cap charges as expected
However, during the low pulse the cap does not discharge.
V(n003) is the pulse and V(n002) is the voltage at the capacitors positive node

Question: Why doesn't the capacitor discharge on the during the low pulse?

One obvious problem is that you are trying to discharge a 100uF capacitor through a 1k resistor. That gives you a time constant (R x C) of 100 ms. Your pulse is 0.5 ms, so there's not enough time to discharge it. A capacitor discharges 36.8% in one time constant, so it needs more than one to get close to full discharge, rule of thumb is five time constants, that should get you under 1% charge.
You either need to reduce the time constant to
$$
\frac{0.5 ms}{5} = 100 us
$$
or increase the discharge time to
$$
100ms\times5 = 500 ms
$$
And that's assuming your switching arrangement works at all. Start with fixing the timing, then see if the transistors switch as you expect.

Thank you so much! Fixing this got the capacitor discharging properly!
Sorry but I do not have enough reputation to upvote.

As stated in GodJihyo's answer, you do not leave enough time for the capacitor to discharge.
One thing that may confuse you is that you are taking the capacitor voltage measurement with respect to the GND which will be a floating (almost, because M1 is off so the connection is open) node whilst the capacitor discharges. To get the correct measurement, either move the GND connection to the capacitor's bottom-end, or change the measurement statement by holding the mouse left button whilst the cursor is on the capacitor's top-end and release whilst the cursor is on the capacitor's bottom end. That will give you a statement like V(n001, n00x) where n00x is the net name of the bottom-end.

Yes! I was getting confused because the positive terminal on the capacitor was jumping to 24 volts at the beginning of discharging. I believe that was because the the rds on of the nmos was super low so the positive terminal of V1 was effectively connected to the negative terminal of C1 making the voltage at the positive terminal of C1 24V relative to ground. This is very cool!
